# An effective way to implement Threads in Java on many DB records

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading

I am in the development stages of an experimental system in Java with a heavy MySQL DB, containing thousands of records, for each of which is required to perform a number of operations, and in parallel.

I'm well aware of using Java Threads, but I do not know what is the best/efficient way to use it on masses of records from DB.

Suppose we look at the following DB table:

```
Table technicians
    ID          NUMBER
    DISTRICT_CODE       NUMBER NOT NULL
    EVENT_START_DATE    DATE NOT NULL
    EVENT_END_DATE      DATE NOT NULL
    INCHARGE        NUMBER NOT NULL
    EFFECTIVE_FROM      DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL
    EFFECTIVE_TO        DATE
    STATUS          NUMBER NOT NULL
```

Then we'll perform the following extraction:

```
SELECT * FROM technicians WHERE INCHARGE = 23;
```

Now, I'm now seriously debating whether to put the extracted info into a List (for example, ArrayList), or other data structure, (Note that each extraction contains about 4000 records, and it occurs every 3 seconds over and over again) and how to implement Thread for each of the records individually.

The naive idea that has been raised, is that after querying the DB and receiving the information, go through each record entry in a loop (sql.hasNext () e.g.) and run the ThreadPoolExecutor object on each record, but I tend to believe that there are more efficient and faster ways.

Any suggestion is welcome

Edit: I see questions have been raised about the actions to be taken for each of the records, so I will try to answer that.

For each line, we will run several different APIs for each field to ensure its correctness type of answer (e.g. correct, incorrect, correct but the value is short, etc.) on so on.

It is important for me to note that each of the actions occurs towards an API that is external to the system (located on a different remote server), so sometimes for a single field, several calls to different APIs will be made, so high power and parallel work are important.

For example:

For the INCHARGE field - we will send the value to an external API source that will check the data, and if the information is correct then we will send the field again to another API and we will get information related to it.

Comment: Without providing more details about what kind of operations are done it's difficult to answer. Also you haven't stated if there are any requirements on the runs over the datasets like max execution time or whether there can only be a single running operation at a time and so on.

Comment: might be wrong, but sounds to me like a perfect scenario for Spring Batch. Might be worth considering.

Comment: Type of workload is very important when multi threading for database tasks. If it's mostly reads then that is fine but if you have more writes then you can run into conflicting writes working on the same data. If you try to solve that with locking records then you cause blocking stalemates.

If each thread has it's own set of data that doesn't interact with other threads data then everything is thread safe.

Comment: What exactly do you mean “perform a number of operations”? Processing a few thousand records every three seconds is not much of a load if you are just doing some calculations or building a report, and would not spawning threads. I’m voting to close as unclear, needing detail.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker I just edit my post, , I hope things are a little clearer now. In any case, the actions are not refer to simple mathematical operations or using local functions, but using an API that is external to the system.

Comment: I suspect the 4000 threads will not finish in 3 seconds.  That will lead to the system stumbling over itself, betting behinder and behinder.

Comment: @RickJames you're absolutely right. This is why I opened the question for consultation, how the process can be streamlined, so that the system does not stumble upon itself and execute the maximum possible queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Better design:**

Don't use cron or Events for a repeating task that *might* take longer than the allotted interval to finish.

Instead, have a separate program that runs through all 4000 items (taking as long as needed), then starts over.

**Further comments:**

It may not matter much whether you use multi-processing versus multi-threading.

If threading, remember that MySQL connections are not thread-safe; you must use a separate connection for each thread.

While MySQL can easily handle 4000 *idle* connections, it does not do well with 4000 queries *active simultaneously*.  (Often 100 is challenging for it.  Often, the solution is to speed up the queries.)

Splitting the 4000 into multiple threads may not be useful.  It is rarely useful to have more threads than CPU cores.  They stumble over each other in new ways -- how the OS deals with coordination.

Splitting up the 4000 complicates this extra process -- You may need a master program that is watching its children to see when it is time to start over.  Or (probably better), have, say, 20 threads each doing a specific 200 tasks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to process some rows in a database every three seconds. For each time, you want to query for about four thousand rows. Each of those rows needs to be individually processed, without regard for the other rows in that table. It sounds like you are not updating the rows, but instead sending the row’s data via calls to other services such as making web services calls.

## Yes, use executor services

So load you data into memory, as the volume seems low. Define a class to hold the data for each row. Since we are using this class primarily to communicate data transparently and immutable, define the class as a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395).

```
record Technician ( int id , LocalDate eventStart , … ) {}
```

Instantiate these `Technician` objects as you loop the result set from your query.

For each `Technician` object, pass to the constructor of a class implementing `Callable`. The `run` method of that class defines the work you need to do in processing that row’s data, passing to web service calls, etc.

A `Callable` returns a value. Let's define another record to signal success/failure and the ID of the record.

```
record TechnicianProcessingResult ( int id , boolean succeeded ) {}
```

Make that record be the type of our `Callable`.

```java
class ProcessTechnicianTask implements Callable< TechnicianProcessingResult > {

    private final Technician technician ;

    ProcessTechnicianTask( Technician t ) { // Constructor.
        this.technician = t ;
    }
 
    public TechnicianProcessingResult call() {
        System.out.println( "Processing technician Id " + this.technician.id );
        …
        return new TechnicianProcessingResult( this.technician.id , true ) ;
        … or …
        return new TechnicianProcessingResult( this.technician.id , false ) ;
    }
}
```

Instantiate a task for each `Technician` object you instantiated for each row retrieved from database. Collect the tasks.

```
List< ProcessTechnicianTask > tasks = new ArrayList<>() ;
…
tasks.add( new ProcessTechnicianTask( nthTechnician ) ) ;
```

Submit that collection of tasks an executor service you have already established. Generally specify almost as many threads as you have CPU cores available.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 5 ) ;
…
List< Future< TechnicianProcessingResult > > futures = executorService.invokeAll( tasks , 3 , TimeUnit.SECONDS ) ;
```

Notice the time-out arguments, to fire in case something goes wrong and your tasks take too much time to complete.

Check the list of futures to see if they are [done](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#isDone()), and if any were [canceled](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#isCancelled()), and check their result object.

You want to repeat that every three seconds. So also create a single-threaded `ScheduledExecutorService`. Schedule a repeating task, a `Runnable` or `Callable`, that does the above work of database query, instantiating `Technician` objects, assigning each to a `ProcessTechnicianTask` object, all submitted to our other executor service.

Be sure to gracefully shutdown your executor service objects. Otherwise their backing thread pools may continue running indefinitely, like a zombie ‍♂️. See boilerplate code provided in the Javadoc.

All of this has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. So search to learn more.

You seemed to have had this approach in mind. But you wondered if there is "more efficient and faster ways". No, I do not see any better way. Your bottleneck here is making network calls to your API, presumably web services calls. Creating the record objects, collecting them, and submitting them to the executor services will be very fast compared to the threads waiting around for a response back from the network calls.

## Project Loom

The one thing that might dramatically improve performance in your scenario is the [virtual threads](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/425) and [structured concurrency](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8277129) promised by [Project Loom](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main).

In current Java, each Java thread is mapped directly to a host OS thread. Each of your few threads will sit idle during the web services calls, halting execution until those calls return. These threads are heavyweight, so we cannot have very many.

In Project Loom, many virtual threads are mapped to each host OS thread. These virtual threads are lightweight, so we can have thousands, even millions. When a virtual thread blocks, such as waiting for your web services call to return, that virtual thread is "parked"/"dismounted" from the host OS thread so that another virtual thread might use the host thread. So other virtual threads can get stuff done while the previous virtual thread waits for its web services call to return.

In your situation, many more web services calls could be placed at a time, rather than only a few at a time. The CPU cores on your machine stay much busier, getting more of your rows processed in less time. You might see a multiple-fold improvement in your processing time.

Project Loom is unfinished, but under active development. Experimental builds are [available now](https://jdk.java.net/loom/), based on early-access Java 19. See articles, interviews, and presentations with team members including Ron Pressler and Alan Bateman.